# How to get statusCode of HTTP post action in Logic Apps?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

```
"actions": {
            "HTTP_Post_for_procedure_is_in-scope": {
              "type": "Http",
              "inputs": {
                "method": "POST",
                "uri": "@{parameters('<...>')}",
                "body": "@triggerBody()"
              },
              "runAfter": {
                "Log_start_of_request_processing": [
                  "Succeeded",
                  "Failed",
                  "Skipped",
                  "TimedOut"
                ]
              },
              "trackedProperties": {
                "ActionName": "HTTP Post for procedure is in scope",
                "uri": "@action()['inputs']['uri']",
                "message": "@action()['inputs']['body']['message']"
                //want output status code here
              }
            },
```

Comment: What research have you done?  Anything you tried?

Comment: 1. "statusCode": "@outputs('HTTP_Post_for_procedure_is_in-scope')?['statusCode']" - not worked
2. "statusCode": "@action()['outputs']['statusCode']"  - not worked

Comment: Hi, it is better to edit the question, since you cannot format a comment.  The comment you posted would be great formatted as code in the question.

Comment: First I have tried 1. "statusCode": "@outputs('HTTP_Post_for_procedure_is_in-scope')?['statusCode']" - not worked    then I have tried to do it using 
2. "statusCode": "@action()['outputs']['statusCode']"  - not worked...   Can not edit original post as its an image.

Answer (score 3):

Or simply:

@outputs('action_name')['statusCode']

example:

```
"expression": {
                "and": [
                    {
                        "not": {
                            "equals": [
                                "@outputs('Get_a_document')['statusCode']",
                                404
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to get it by using:

> @actionOutputs('ActionName').statusCode

Answer (score 0):

This works too:

@action()['outputs']['statusCode']